# python multiple variable if condition

Tags: python, combinatorics

I'm new to programming and would like to ask in Python if I have a m-list of conditions and would like to know if n of these are true in a if statment:

eg:

```
if (a == b) or (c == d) or (e == f):
```

would return 1,2 or all 3 true, but I want to know if only 2 of these are true

eg:

```
if ((a == b) and ((c == d) or (e == f))) or (((a == b) or (c == d)) and (e == f)) or (((a == b) or (e == f)) and (c == d)):
```

is there any easier way to do this? What to do if (m,n) is large?

Thanks

Comment: Besides being unwieldy, your solution does not give the correct answer. It will also return `True` if all three conditions are true...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `True` is actually the integer `1`, you could do

```
if (a==b) + (c==d) + (e==f) == 2:
```

For larger sets of conditions, you could use `sum()`:

```
conditions = [a==b, c==d, d==e, f==g, ...]
if sum(conditions) == 3:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 6):

```
[a == b, c == d, e == f].count(True)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the conditions are equality tests which are guaranteed to return either True or False, then of course you can use @Tim's answer.

Otherwise, you can work out a slight variant using a list of conditions which will work with any conditional statement

```
conditions = [a == b, 
    c == d,
    e == f,
    e,
    f is None]
```

And then do a simple sum using:

```
sum(1 if cond else 0 for cond in conditions) >= m
```

Note that this approach works if the conditions are boolean in nature as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 0
for cond in list:
  n += bool(cond)
```